# How to hide XML file with markers in google maps?

Tags: xml, maps

How do I hide the name of php file, which generate XML file with markers for dispaly in google maps??

I have the following JS code:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;


  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("google_map.php", function(data) {

    var seskupene = [];

    var xml = data.responseXML;

    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var street = markers[i].getAttribute("street");
      var psccity = markers[i].getAttribute("psccity");
      var phone = markers[i].getAttribute("phone");
      var mail = markers[i].getAttribute("mail");
      var href = markers[i].getAttribute("href");
      var image = markers[i].getAttribute("image");
      var coord = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));

      var html = '<div class="g_div">'+
                    '<div class="g_title">' + name + '</div>'+
                    '<div class="g_img"><img src="' + image + '"></div>'+
                    '<div class="g_data">'+
                        '<div>' + street + '</div><div>' + psccity + '</div>'+
                        '<div>&nbsp;</div><div><a href="">' + mail + '</a></div><div>' + phone + '</div>'+
                        '<div>&nbsp;</div><div><a href="">Detail autoškoly ...</a></div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                 '</div>';
```

File google_map.php returns XML file with markers. I don't want someone entering into your browser url [http://.../google_map.php] and download XML file with data.

How do I secure?? Thanks for your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really hide it, but you can make it so that only the original browser can download it easily by using extra info, like a session cookie, so just knowing the exact URL is not enough. You can add more parameters to the URL, like a checksum of some other data which must match, and which can change on each request; or just a random number that must agree with the value you stored in your session on the server.

Answer (score 0):

It is in my opinion not possible to hide this, but you can at least make the life of scrapers a bit harder. One possibility is what bart told you.
Another possibility is to check the referrer. BUT: this is not bullet proof either!
Try something like this:

```
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (!preg_match("/yourdomain.com/",$referrer)) {
    header('Location: http://www.yourdomain.com'); 
    //send the user to your startpage
}
else{
//your code to generate the XML
}
```